# Lighttpd server configuration to run cgi binaries using fast cgi

Tags: fastcgi, lighttpd, gsoap, cgi-bin

I have a lighttpd webserver runnning in a linux embedded box. Lighttpd have got Fastcgi enabled for php. How to edit my lighttpd.conf such that to run cgi binaries using fastcgi? Also my linux box doesn't have cgi-bin folder in it's document root.

I am quoting the excerpt from lighttpd.conf which enables fastcgi and php configuration. Also, it can be seen that cgi.assign is commented.

```
server.modules              = (
#                               "mod_rewrite",
                                "mod_redirect",
#                               "mod_alias",
                                "mod_access",
#                               "mod_trigger_b4_dl",
#                               "mod_auth",
#                               "mod_status",
#                               "mod_setenv",
                                "mod_fastcgi",
#                               "mod_proxy",
#
```

and

```
## read fastcgi.txt for more info
## for PHP don't forget to set cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1 in the php.ini
fastcgi.server             = ( ".php" =>
                               ( "localhost" =>
                                 (
                                   "socket" => "/tmp/php-fastcgi.socket",
                                   "bin-path" => "/bin/php-cgi -c /etc/php.ini"
                                 )
                               )
                            )

#### CGI module
#cgi.assign                 = ( ".pl"  => "/usr/bin/perl",
#                               ".cgi" => "/usr/bin/perl" )
#
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile php with cgi option. Basically its a standalone php.

Comment: I have php compiled with --enable-fastcgi option. Whether I can run other cgi binaries(gSOAP) with php-cgi ? if so, how ?
You can see the PHP modules in my linux box as listed

[/bin/php-cgi -m --->

[PHP Modules],
cgi-fcgi,
date,
libxml,
Reflection,
session,
SimpleXML,
standard,
]

Comment: You have already configured the binary path. I can't see anything wrong. Can you post more of your config file? What is the error message?